# Функция возвращающая оптимальную суму

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать функцию которая возвращает оптимальный результат. К примеру, есть общая сума 150 и нужно вернуть общую сумму элементов(list) которые максимально приближенны к ней.

Есть функция returnSum которая принимает следующие аргументы:
sum - максимальная сума,
amount - количество элементов,
list - список элементов

```
const returnSum = (sum, amount, list) => {

// code

return null;

}

returnSum(174, 3, [51, 56, 58, 59, 61]); //173
returnSum(163, 3, [50]); // null
```

Примерно так должно выглядеть, не могу понять каким образом это реализовать

Comment: Это вроде с codewars задача. Вы должны ее сами решить, либо пропустить, в этом и есть суть "битвы".

Comment: Начните с перебора всех троек элементов из данного массива.

Comment: @Pilaton это не с кодварс, я хочу её разобрать чтобы понять как подобные задачи решать, а то как-то туго выходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да делать как и любую задачу на поиска максимума/минимума

- задаётся переменная где будет храниться дельта. инициализируем нулём. Ну и например переменную, которая хранит сумму чисел.
- идём циклом от начала в конец или от конца в начало, берём по три элемента и суммируем их.
- находим дельту от суммы трёх чисел и сравниваемого числа. записываем в переменную, сумму - в переменную с суммой
- на следующих итерациях всё так же берём по три числа, находим дельту и сравниваем с дельтой в переменной. Если меньше - то пишем её и сумму в сумму.

остальные проверки уже дело десятое

---

А в целом, нужно брать по три числа всегда - это единственную проблему, которую тут нужно решить, на мой взгляд.

```
51, 56, 58, 59, 61:

51, 56, 58
51, 56, 59,
51, 56, 61
51, 58, 59
51, 58, 61
51, 59, 61
56, 58, 59
56, 58, 61
56, 59, 61
58, 59, 61
```

Comment: Не совсем понял каким именно образом делать перебор, можете показать пример?

Comment: @Identikit Три вложенных цикла

Comment: @Identikit ну лично вам я бы предложил сделать три цикла. Потому что это будет для вашего понимания и проще в реализации. Первый цикл от `i=0` до `length - 3`, вложенный от `j = i +1` третий от `k = i + 2` (вроде так %) )....... не забывая соблюдать границы конца массива...чтобы не выползти за границы массива..... чтобы точно написать - нарисуйте на листочке массив, посчитайте сколько раз должен исполняться каждый цикл....... просто на листочке......а потом это перенести в код